# Generalizing the sum of squared second differences to graphs?

Tags: soft-question, graph-laplacian

Suppose I have a sequence of numbers $x = (x_1, x_2, \dots x_n)$.

I’m interested in the sum of squared differences: $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (x_{i+1} - x_i)^2.$$

I can treat the sequence as a function on the $n$ vertices of a path graph $G$ and form the Laplacian matrix $L_G$. Then the sum above is simply $x^\top L_G x$.

Taking it one step further, I’d like to look at the second differences: $$\sum_{i=2}^{n-1} (x_{i+1} - 2x_i + x_{i-1})^2.$$ Again, this can be expressed of the form $x^\top M x$ for a matrix $M$.

My question is: can $M$ be defined for a more general graph than just the path graph in a meaningful/interesting way? It’s almost like the “square” of the Laplacian, but not exactly.

Comment: What do you mean by “can _M_ be defined for a more general graph than just the path graph in a meaningful/interesting way?”? If you are interested in $$\sum_{i=2}^{n-1} (x_{i+1} -2x_i +x_{i-1})^2,$$ you can take the Laplacian of the graph path _L_, your sequence of numbers _x_, compute $u:=Lx$, suppress the first and last entries of _u_ (i.e., let $A:=[{\bf 0}_{n-2}, I_{n-2}, {\bf 0}_{n-2}]$, then let $u \gets Au$), then perform $u^{\rm T}u$. Indeed, you end up with something of the form $x^{\rm T} Mx$, where $M=LA^{\rm T}\!\!AL$ is “almost like the “square” of the Laplacian, but not exactly”.

Comment: "Suppress first and last entries" doesn't seem to generalize well to non-path graphs

Comment: “Suppress first and last entries” has nothing to do with the actual graph but the computation of $Lx$. Instead of $x^{\rm T}\!LA^{\rm T}\!\!ALx$, then just do $x^{\rm T}\!L^2x$ minus $(x_1-x_2)^2+(x_n-x_{n-1})^2$, for those two terms aren’t in the second differences sum. For sums of squares of higher-order differences (of order $k$), you are going to use a Laplacian whose $k/2$ diagonals both above and below the main diagonal are filled with $-1$ (the order $k$ must be even for the matrix to be a Laplacian). The entries you would suppress from $Lx$ are then the first $k/2$ and last $k/2$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't follow. I don't see why the diagonals would be filled with -1 for a non-path graph. If you have a construction that works for all graphs, I would appreciate if you could add it as an answer to the question.

Comment: No, there’s no “construction that works for all graphs”. Rather, the type of recurrence you are interested in is what is going to shape the Laplacian you are going to use. E.g., the sum $$\sum_{i=3}^{n-2} (x_{i+2}+x_{i+1}-4x_n+x_{n-1}+x_{n-2})^2$$ can be calculated as $x^{\rm T}\!L^2x$ minus some terms, where _L_ is $$\begin{bmatrix} 2&-1&-1\\ -1&3&-1&-1\\ -1&-1&4&-1&-1\\ &-1&-1&4&-1&-1\\ &&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\\ &&&-1&-1&4&-1&-1\\ &&&&-1&-1&3&-1\\ &&&&&-1&-1&2 \end{bmatrix}.$$